# combining two bitmaps into one bitmap throws an OutOfMemoryException

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I am using the code below to combine two bitmaps into one bitmap:

```
real = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.real);

apply.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        loadBitmapFromView(real).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bs);
        byte[] byteArray = bs.toByteArray();
        i.putExtra("bittext", byteArray);
        setResult(RESULT_OK,i);
        finish();
    }
});

public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);                
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
    v.draw(c);
    return b;
}
```

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/bg">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/real"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="25dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/text"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

        <ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"enter code here
            android:id="@+id/imagetext" 
            android:scaleType="matrix"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <Button android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/text"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>`enter code here`

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/apply"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/text"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/apply" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Error occurred when the `@+id/apply` button is clicked, it can not go to the previous activity along with the bitmap. this problem was occurred only one device (Videocon mobile only). What is the issue, and how do I fix it?

Comment: If its necessary for you to store image in `PNG` format then store it in `JPG` format. Replace line `loadBitmapFromView(real).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bs);` with  `loadBitmapFromView(real).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bs);`

Comment: @zanky is it reduce bitmap size?

Comment: Here you are passing image through intent. Therefore it might be throwing error.Instead of that use static bitmap object and use it in other activity by statically invoking.

Comment: Yes, converting it in `JPEG` format will only reduce its size not resolution.

Comment: @zanky Thanks for reply,but here i am passing bytearray[] to other activity instead of bitmap

Comment: Therefore, i am saying that instead of passing this bitmap as bytearray, declare this bitmap variable as `public static` and use it in another activity. In some devices, if bytearray size is large than it throws `OutOfMemory` error. I faced same issue and then i solved it with static bitmap.